# laravel notification does not work for me

Tags: laravel

I want to send an email to user with a message as below:

MessageController.php:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

    $message = new Message;
    $message->title = $request->title; 
    $message->body = $request->body; 
    $message->offer_id = $request->offer_id; 
    $message->user_id = $user_id; 
    $message->with_profile = $request->employeeProfile;
    $message->save();
    //return response()->json($message); -> this gives correct message

    $offer = Offer::where('id', '=', $request->offer_id)->first();
    //here I'm trying to get user Id, basing on offer (I knot I should use other way, but I'll correct it later
    $user = User::where('id', '=', $offer->user_id)->first();

    $user->notify(new OfferMessage($message)); -> this gives error "Undefined variable: message" 

    return response()->json(['created' => true], 201);
}
```

The problem is that it gives me an error: "Undefined variable: message", while I'm reciving correct message when I uncoment "return response()->json($message);"

What am I doing wrong here?

edit:

My Message.php class: (I don't have OfferMessage class)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Notifications\OfferMessage;

class Message extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;
}
```

edit2: Notifications/OfferMessage.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

use App\Message;

class OfferMessage extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
        public $message;
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('You've got new message: '.$message->offer_id)
                    ->line($message->title)
                    ->line($message->body)
                    ->line('Sent by:'.$message->user_id)
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add `OfferMessage` class in Question ?

Comment: @rkj I just added my Message class

Comment: no, `OfferMessage` class

Comment: you need to add `OfferMessage` class as notification, check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications

Comment: OfferMessage class? Message class is not enough? I added OfferMessage notification, so every new notification require new class model?

Comment: i am talking about `OfferMessage` notification class. do you have it ? if yes then it it also in your question

Comment: Yes, I edited my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173451/discussion-between-rkj-and-gileneusz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `OfferMessage` Class toMail method

Change `$message` **TO** `$this->message`

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line("You've got new message: ".$this->message->offer_id)
                    ->line($this->message->title)
                    ->line($this->message->body)
                    ->line('Sent by:'.$this->message->user_id)
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }
```

Comment: I'm so stupid, lol. Next error: "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded" :)

Comment: using laravel is frustrating :/

Comment: this is wrong `'You've got new message: '.$this->message->offer_id` you are not escaping ' like this \'